# Instance members can't be accessed from a static method dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a static method,

and I tried to pass a variable into that method, but it said to me

**Instance members can't be accessed from a static method Flutter**

can you help me?

this is my method:

```
 static void backgroundCallback(List<LocationData> locations) async {
        print(x);
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = ...........
```

can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is clear, you are trying to use the value of, or modify the value of, an instance member (i.e. a non-static field) of your class which is most probably x in your case (since you didn't show enough code), from within a static method,

Why is this forbidden?

Suppose you have not created any instance of your class yet but you decided to call this static method which uses the instance member, then how will we know what value of this instance member to use when it is already not initialized yet

Solution:

either remove the code that access this member or make this member itself  static

Comment: thanks for the help, but I want to ask you a question, my variable here come from the constructor, can I use it in my static class??

Comment: If you apply the same reasoning in the answer, you will find that you can't, because maybe you call the static method before creating an instance of the class and by that time the variable you want will not be available, please mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question :)